# Ignore table rows from filtering with jQuery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table:

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <th>ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="showRowBelow()">1</td><td>Test1</td><td>Desc1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0 0 0;border:0px">Inserted after click</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="showRowBelow()">2</td><td>Test1</td><td>Desc1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0 0 0;border:0px">Inserted after click</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="showRowBelow()">3</td><td>Test1</td><td>Desc1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0 0 0;border:0px">Inserted after click</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td onclick="showRowBelow()">4</td><td>Test1</td><td>Desc1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0 0 0;border:0px">Inserted after click</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On this table I add jQuery tablesorter with integrated filter plugin (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>var $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j("#mytable").tablesorter({
         theme: 'blue',

        widgets: ["", "filter"],

        widgetOptions : {
          filter_childRows : false,     

          filter_columnFilters : true,      

          filter_cssFilter : 'tablesorter-filter',

          filter_filteredRow   : 'filtered',

          filter_formatter : null,

          filter_functions : null,

          filter_hideFilters : false, // true, (see note in the options section above)

          filter_ignoreCase : true,

          filter_liveSearch : true,

          filter_reset : 'button.reset',

          filter_searchDelay : 100,

          filter_serversideFiltering: false,        

          filter_startsWith : false,        

          filter_useParsedData : false

          }
       });
});
```

**Question**

Is it possible to exclude all table rows with style property "display:none"? These rows must be always *invisible* until a click on table cell with the 'ID' content is performed.

At the moment these invisible rows are filtered and therefore also shown when typing characters into input filter field.

Well, I can register an event which is triggered after filter action and there I can change style to "display:none" for these rows again. But I think this is not a good solution (performance etc.).

Answer (score 0):

To make the filter widget ignore child rows content, you'll need to add a class name of "tablesorter-childRow" (modified by the [`cssChildRow` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#csschildrow)):

```
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow" style="display:none">
  <td colspan="3" style="padding: 0 0 0;border:0px">Inserted after click</td>
</tr>
```

Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows-filtered.html).

Comment: Sorry this did not work. Maybe you can create a jsFiddle example?